# Figure size on LatticeExtra R for Power BI

Tags: r, powerbi

I'm doing a 3D histogram with latticeExtra in Power BI. The output figure is too small and covers only a small fraction of the entire box. I haven't been able to increase the figure.

At first I thought it was an issue of Power BI, but I haven't been able with RStudio either.

I'm using the following code:

```
library(latticeExtra)
cloud(Value~AxisX+AxisY, dataset, panel.3d.cloud=panel.3dbars, col.facet='red',  
        xbase=50, ybase=5, scales=list(arrows=FALSE, col=1), xlab = "xval",ylab="yval",zlab="Value",rot=c(40,50,50),par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent"),layout.widths = list(axis.panel = rep(c(1, 0),  c(1, 50)))))
```

Not being able to increase it, I've also tried putting transparent background, but it remains white.

Thank you very much for your help!